# Configure Solr not to bring any results when search for stopwords or blank space

Tags: solr, websphere-commerce

We use Apache solr as an embeded search engine in IBM Websphere Commerce v7, and facing the below issue when configuring solr unstructured (content) search for our e-commerce based application.Recently we configured solr content search (unstructured search) in our application.

Whenever we search for any stopwords (mentioned in the stopwords.txt such as - about, among, an, a, the etc.), it brings all results from the solr. I checked the solr Analyzer in the admin console, the search field is configured with StopFilterFactory, hence Solr ignores the stopword and passes a blank string as a solr query, which brings all results.

However, as per our requirement, we want to configure solr to prevent fetching any results incase there is an empty query, or the input word is a stopword.

It seems like, the default behavior of solr is, bring all results in case of empty query.

Any help in this topic will be appreciated.

Thanking you in advance.

Regards,

Jitendriya Dash

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [q.alt](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#q.alt) parameter, I believe you have it configured as "*:*" (match all query).